# What is the proper dependency configuration for Vaadin CssLayout

Tags: spring-boot, vaadin, vaadin14

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
    <artifactId>vaadin-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

`SpringBoot 2`
`Vaadin 12.0.3`

Horizontal and Vertical Layouts work fine for me. I wanted to try CssLayout but don't see it in the class path. Examples that show CssLayout at work, import from `com.vaadin.ui.CssLayout`. I don't see that package.

Is dependency configuration incorrect, or have things changed in latest Vaadin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The layout components have changed in Vaadin 10+ from Vaadin 8. There are Vertical/HorizontalLayouts, but they behave slightly differently, since implementation is now based on CSS FlexBox. There are also API changes. CssLayout does not exists anymore, there is class called Div instead, which has replaced it.